# a property of skew-symmetric matrix (arising from game theory)

Tags: linear-algebra, game-theory

I know for a fact that for any skew-symmetric matrix $A$, there cannot be a vector $x\geq 0$ so that
$Ax\geq e$, where $e$ is the vector of all $1$'s. However, the proof I have is very indirect and is based on the connection of (2-person zero-sum) game theory with the primal-dual theory of linear programs.

Is there a more direct proof?

Answer (score 6):

I assume that by "a vector $x \geq 0$" you mean a vector with entries in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, and "$Ax \geq e$" means the entries of the vector $Ax$ are all real numbers greater than or equal to $1$. In particular, I assume that you are working over $\mathbb{R}$ throughout. Please let me know if I have misunderstood.

Assuming my understanding is correct, note $x \cdot Ax = A^Tx \cdot x = -A x \cdot x = -x \cdot Ax$, and so in particular $x \cdot Ax = 0$. On the other hand, if $x \geq 0$ and $Ax \geq e$, then $x \cdot Ax \geq x \cdot e \geq 0$. This vanishes only when $x=0$, which would force $Ax = 0 \not\geq e$.

Comment: Thanks. I see the proof after you observed that for any skew-symmetric $A$, $x^T A x$ has to be 0 for any vector $x$. (I wondered if it has a geometric meaning, when viewing $A$ has an infinitesimal rotation.)  I think what you mean next is: either $x$ has a positive entry, in this case, the corresponding entry in $Ax$ must vanish, or that $x$ is the zero vector. Either case, $Ax \geq e$ cannot hold. Thanks again for your solution!

Comment: @Thomas Note than an infinitesimal rotation has the form $\mathbf{1} + \mathbf{A}$. Then $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{Ax}=0$  is just an expression of the fact that the length doesn't change under rotation (up to quadratic terms). Actually, it is this property from which one derives that infinitesimal rotations are represented by skew-symmetric matrices in the first place: if you expand $||(\mathbf{1}+\mathbf{A})\mathbf{x}||^2 - ||\mathbf{x}||^2=O(\mathbf{A}^2)$ you end up requiring $\mathbf{A}^T-\mathbf{A}=0$.

Comment: @Thomas the real geometrical background to this is that any rotation matrix can be obtained as $\exp(\mathbf{A})$ (using the power series), and $\mathbf{1} + \mathbf{A}$ happen to be the first two terms in the power series expansion. By identifying the entries of the skew-symmetric matrix with vector components in the usual way that you probably know (otherwise think how you would fill a matrix $\mathbf{M}$ such that $\mathbf{Mx}=\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{x}$ and use that relation between $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{a}$), this ends up giving you the angle-axis representation of rotations.